# не правильно выводит сумму

Tags: java

Пожалуйста, помогите мне, я нaписала код, который содержит 2 метода. первый метод позволяет пользователю ввести 2 числа a второй считывает сумму этих двух чисел который ввел пользователь. Проблема заключается в том что  у меня в коде не правильно выводит  сумму -при любых чисел код выводит 0.Ниже представлены 2 класса Metods и Main.

```
public class Metods {

int nr1,nr2;
   
 public void enterNum() {

        Scanner scaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter nr1");
        int nr1 = scaner.nextInt();
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter nr2");
        int nr2 = scanner2.nextInt();
    }

public void suma(){

    int suma=nr1+nr2;
    System.out.println(suma);
    }

}


public class Main extends Metods {
    
public static void main(String[]args) {
  

Main s=new Main();
  s.enterNum();
  s.suma();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри метода `enterNum()` вы объявляйте новые переменные и записывайте туда значения, а надо:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Metods {

    int nr1,nr2;

    public void enterNum() {
        Scanner scaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter nr1");
        nr1 = scaner.nextInt();
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter nr2");
        nr2 = scanner2.nextInt();
    }

    public void suma(){

        int suma=nr1+nr2;
        System.out.println(suma);
    }

}
```

```
public class Main extends Metods {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Main s=new Main();
        s.enterNum();
        s.suma();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое ,помогли!!